# document.getElementById() doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html

No much to say,

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var x = document.getElementById('btn1');
            alert(x);
        </script>
            <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Clickme" onclick="alert('1')" />
    </body>
</html>
```

The alert message is `null` instead of a message contain details of the object or something like that.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Put your script AFTER the actual element, otherwise by the time your javascript code runs, there's not yet such element in the DOM.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Clickme" onclick="alert('1')" />
        <script>
            var x = document.getElementById('btn1');
            alert(x);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively put your script in a DOM ready event to ensure that the DOM is fully loaded by the browser before attempting to manipulate it:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                var x = document.getElementById('btn1');
                alert(x);
            };
        </script>
        <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Clickme" onclick="alert('1')" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Any reason for the downvote?

Comment: I have upvoted, I don't know who have downvoted.

Comment: I know, it would have been nice if the downvoter left a comment explaining why he downvoted. Maybe he found a mistake or something wrong in the answer.

Comment: Why will anyone downvote this??it's a clear solution..

Comment: downvote for this nice solution?? why??

Answer (score 7):

You need to run the javascript **after** the html s read/rendered...

Try this instead:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Clickme" onclick="alert('1')" />
        <script>
            var x = document.getElementById('btn1');
            alert(x);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Or you can add a window load function so the script only runs after the page has loaded. Like:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            window.onload = function(){
                var x = document.getElementById('btn1');
                alert(x);
            }
        </script>
            <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Clickme" onclick="alert('1')" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you and Darin the same person? ;)

Comment: @GolezTrol, haha :) nope, but we did think the same here... he answered **1 second** before me :)

Comment: And you both made the same addition at almost the same time as well, so I guess you both deserver some upvotes.

Comment: @GolezTrol, yeah, that was fun actually. I edited ,my answer and he had done the dame edit (1 second before me, again...)

Answer (score 0):

Its because your are trying to access the **button information before its created in the dom of the document**.Give the script a the end of the body like below

```
<html>
    <body>

        <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Clickme" onclick="alert('1')" />
        <script>
            var x = document.getElementById('btn1');
            alert(x);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6sT6W/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript codes run from top to bottom. In the line `alert(x)`, there is no `input#btn1` yet.
You can use:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var x = document.getElementById('btn1');
    alert(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the `script` is executed first there is no element with id `#btn1` loaded in the dom. So execute the `script` after the element is loaded.

Like this,

```
    <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Clickme" onclick="alert('1')" />
    <script>
        var x = document.getElementById('btn1');
        alert(x);
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function call()
     {
        var x = document.getElementById('btn1').value.trim();//or use "=<%btn1.ClientID%>"
        alert(x);
     }
      </script>
```

put this function `onClientClick` event of your button.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentReady',function(){
    var x = document.getElementById('btn1');
    alert(x);
};
```

Using 'DOMContentReady' event is better than 'window.onload' if your broswer support.